# Moving multiple imageviews randomly without collision

Tags: android, algorithm, android-animation, game-physics

I have a List of `ImageView` ~20-25 small icons randomly placed inside `RelativeLayout` without overlapping.

I'm using ImageView's left & top margin to set ImageView on view.

I want to move this ImageViews randomly without collision and without going out of screen for just 10 seconds.

any suggestions?

Comment: Use a SurfaceView and combine a Rect with a Bitmap location

Comment: @LunarWatcher do you have any example ?

Comment: Use a thread, look in the SO documentation it is there too

Comment: and how to apply random animation on them ?

Comment: Path finding...